# How can I customize the highlighting of matching bracket/brace/parenthesis pairs in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code has a feature where it will put a transparent grey (well, usually grey, but can depend on the colour theme) **background and border/outline** around the other bracket corresponding to the current one that is under the cursor/caret, or for the pair around the cursor/caret.

Is it possible to customize that matching brace highlighting in Visual Studio Code?

---

I thought this would be configurable through textmate themes / syntax highlighting settings, but I could not find a syntax highlighting token scope to configure this.

Ultimately I'd like to have a solid color highlight of matching braces, similar to what you would get with the default dark theme in Visual Studio 2013 and 2015.

Comment: dear reader, **1)** if you're interested in colouring _**the brackets themselves**_ (including when bracket pair colourization is enabled) instead of the highlighting of bracket pairs, see [How do I change the colour of brackets in VS Code?](/q/57764284/11107541). **2)** if you're interested in customizing colours of **bracket _guides_**, see [How to change indent guide line color between brackets in VS Code?](/q/47942390/11107541).

Answer (score 36):

For future reference, vscode now has the option to change the color of bracket highlighting by adding this to *settings.json*:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations" : {
        "editorBracketMatch.background": "#f008",
        "editorBracketMatch.border": "#f00"
}
```

Formats supported are *#RGB*, *#RGBA*, *#RRGGBB*, *#RRGGBBAA*. The `rgba(255,255,255,1)` format that seems to work in other places in the settings file appears to not work here.

<s>Only feature that is still missing regarding this subject is bracket highlighting when the cursor is between brackets. They only highlight when one of the brackets is selected. I did not find a current solution searching trough the *Settings* or *workbench.colorCustomizations*.</s>

**Update 2018.04.21**
There is now a plugin called [Bracket Pair Colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer) that does shows the current brackets besides the line number no matter where the cursor is placed within the brakes. But on slower hardware (3nd generation i5 laptop) i encountered slowdowns with it when editing large files (3000+ line php file). And alternate plugin that performs well on the same file and highlights the current indentation is [Guides](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spywhere.guides).

**Update 2019.11.10**
VSCode 1.40 now highlights the brackets enclosing the cursor.

**Update 2021.08.09**
as @desilicius mentioned in the comments Bracket Pair colorizer is no longer maintained by the author. He offers as an alternative [Blockman - Highlight Nested Code Blocks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=leodevbro.blockman)  which has the same functionality but has a totally different look and [Highlight Matching Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag) which is a great plugin but only works on html (and jsx) tags as the name implies.

**Update 2021.08.13**
The VSCode team decided to add bracket pair colorization as a built in feature. It is worked on right now with improvements of 10k x the speed of BPC2. The discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128465#issuecomment-879089188)

Comment: Note: There is a newer Package of the same functionality, but **much faster** by use of the VS Code parsing engine. The name is [Bracket Pair Colorizer **2**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2).

Comment: I've tried it but the 3000+ file has grown to 5000+ and the plugin is still slow.

Comment: Strange that there's no foreground option to change the color of the matched bracket itself.

Comment: Bracket Pair Colorizer 2 is no longer maintained

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Bracket Pair Colorizer 2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2) Extension.

Comment: I came across this looking for a solution to the bug that vscode highlights the wrong indent guide and (while the default incorrect indent guide still shows up) Bracket Pair Colorizer 2 adds it's own correct indent guide. Super cool!

Answer (score 4):

Highlighting and changing colors of brackets in VS Code is now possible.

You can try this extension [Subtle Brackets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafamel.subtle-brackets#overview)  by modifying the following the default values in the .json settings of VS Code:

I changed it like this:

```
"subtleBrackets.bracketPairs": [
    "{}",
    "[]",
    "()",
    "<>"
],
"subtleBrackets.styles": {
    "global": {
        "color": "yellow",
        "borderWidth": "1px",
        "borderStyle": "none none solid none"
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set to "false" the value of .matchbrackets of VS Code.

```
"editor.matchBrackets": false
```

Comment: I'd prefer [**rainbow-brackets**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=2gua.rainbow-brackets) extention or [**Bracket Pair Colorizer**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer) since Subtle Brackets makes only that can be done with "workbench.colorCustomizations"

Comment: Sadly `subtleBrackets` doesn't work for `.vue` files.

Answer (score 1):

**Update September 2021**: The "Bracket pair colorization" feature is now available in VS Code as of the [August 2021 (version 1.60) update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60#_high-performance-bracket-pair-colorization).

Add this to your `settings.json` file:

```
 "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true
```

After saving the file, brackets should instantly be colorized.

Answer (score 1):

Also maybe you will like VSCode extension "Blockman", it highlights nested code blocks. (I am the author of Blockman).

The VSCode extension "Blockman" is a new approach of dealing with brackets, well, it does not highlight brackets themselves, but it renders blocks based on the brackets (curly/square/round brackets/braces), and I think it is a better visual helper for our eyes to perceive code structure more easily, to understand code structure more quickly and more comfortably.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Custom brace highlighting will be even more precise with VSCode 1.76 (Feb. 2022), with [issue 170497](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/170497) and [PR 172758](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/172758): it brings support for coloring a *subset* of the matched bracket.

Example:

```json
"[plaintext]": {
    "editor.language.brackets": [
      ["{", "}"],
      ["(", ")"],
      ["[", "]"]
    ],
    "editor.language.colorizedBracketPairs": [
      ["{", "}"],
      ["<", ">"]
    ]
  },
```

Gives:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2931520/215427587-0144fcaf-6087-46f6-b612-488a813914d1.gif]

This is available with [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) today.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove brackets color and border, you can use hex colors with `0` opacity in your `settings.json`:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorBracketMatch.border": "#ffffff00",
    "editorBracketMatch.background": "#ffffff00",
}
```

You can overwrite any theme:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "[*]": {
    "editorBracketMatch.border": "#ffffff00",
    "editorBracketMatch.background": "#ffffff00",
  }
}
```

In order to target a specific theme, replace the glob character, `*`, with the theme name.

Answer (score 0):

##### CSS Solution

For anyone looking for the actual CSS class because they are doing real custom CSS for VS-Code. The class to edit to adjust display on selected brackets is `.bracket-match`. Here's an example of what I did to add some custom animations to matched bracket pairs in VS-Code.

```css
.bracket-match{
  border-radius:20%;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255, 154, 162, .5), rgba(255, 183, 178, .5), rgba(255, 218, 193, .5), rgba(226, 240, 203, 0.5), rgba(199, 206, 234, 0.5), rgba(199, 206, 234, 0.5));
  background-size: 1000% 100%;
  color: transparent;
  border-bottom:0px !important;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  animation: outlineExpand .6s linear 1, flowBkg 1s linear infinite running;
  transform:translate(1px, 0px);
}

@keyframes flowBkg {
  0%{background-position:0% 51%}
  100%{background-position:100% 50%}
}

@keyframes outlineExpand{
  0%{ 
    outline-width: 3px; 
    outline-color: rgba(255,70,70,.3);

  }
  100%{
    outline-width: 10px;
    outline-offset:30px;
    outline-color: rgba(255,70,70,.3);  
  }
}
```

##### Note:

As of current VS-Code circa Oct 2023 ; It is somewhat tricky to do true custom CSS. See [relevant extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) commonly used for custom CSS and JS within VS-Code.

Answer (score 0):

Customizing the colours of matching bracket highlighting is done through the colour customizations setting and not syntax highlighting customization. Ex. in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorBracketMatch.background": "#ff0000ff",
    "editorBracketMatch.border": "#ff0000ff",
    "editorOverviewRuler.bracketMatchForeground": "#ff0000ff", // for scrollbar
}
```

The supported colour formats include `"#RGB"` (red, green, blue in hex), `"#RGBA"` (added "alpha" (transparency/opacity)), `"#RRGGBB"` (more resolution), `"#RRGGBBAA"`.

If you want to toggle highlighting of matching bracket pairs, use the `editor.matchBrackets` setting (can be set to `"always"`, `"near"`, or `"never"`).