# How to set matching bracket color in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like matching brackets in vscode to be colored instead of given a border/background. What is the correct property for it in setting? Currently I have this:

```
    {
        "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

            "editorBracketMatch.border": "#000",
            "editorBracketMatch.background": "#000"
        }
    }
```

How should I modify this to get the desired result?

Comment: use extension `Bracket Pair Colorizer` version 1 or 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the colour of brackets in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764284/how-do-i-change-the-colour-of-brackets-in-vs-code)

Comment: so you want to change the _foreground_ colour of highlighted matching brackets?

Answer (score 6):

VSCode 1.60, Aug. 2021 will support that directly:

> ### [High performance bracket pair colorization](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_60.md#high-performance-bracket-pair-colorization)
>
> The editor now supports native bracket pair colorization:
>
> [image: Side by side comparison with bracket pair colorization on and off]
>
> Bracket pair colorization can be enabled by setting "**editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true**.
> All colors are themeable and up to six colors can be configured.
>
> We implemented this feature to address performance issues of the famous [Bracket Pair Colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer-2) extension by [CoenraadS](https://github.com/CoenraadS).

In the settings, you can set colors from `foreground1` to `foreground6`:

```json
 colorCustomizations:

{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#3700ff",
    "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#66ff00",
    "editorBracketHighlight.unexpectedBracket.foreground": "#ff0000",
  }
}
```

---

VSCode 1.66 (Feb. 2022) will port over a feature from Bracket Pair Colorizer 2:

> "`bracket-pair-colorizer-2.colorMode`"
>
> - Consecutive brackets share a color pool for all bracket types
>   [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/75278/129780518-3bef1d29-8b79-4ec5-8f24-5d9321617acc.png]
> - Independent brackets allow each bracket type to use its own color pool
>   [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/75278/129780532-0d8d457c-1c33-4c1e-8ed5-e82086c47d3c.png]

See [commit d54c705](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/d54c705f6567958a732ac88b1c3ec4d2303fb026) and setting `editor.bracketPairColorization.useIndependentColorPoolPerBracketType`.

---

See also "[Custom brace highlighting in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75361268/6309)" with VSCode 1.76, Feb. 2023, where you can configure highlights for a *subset* of brackets.